# Alert in Project level equivalent to Quality Profile level in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Whether there are any option to set alerts in Project level instead of Quality Profile level. Since we are using Sonar in organization level and we do not want to create new profile for each project to set different threshold. Please suggest.

Comment: Please, do not double post.

Answer (score 0):

See following thread of discussion: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/SonarQube-Alert-td5019279.html